# why is `npm start` doesn't interpret {{#unless environment.production}}

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, npm-install

```
    </script>
    {{#unless environment.production}}
    <script src="ember-cli-live-reload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {{/unless}}
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  {{#each scripts.polyfills}}
  <script src="{{.}}"></script>
  {{/each}}
  <script>
    System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
      System.import('main');
    }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
```

how is `ng build` knows to interpret row like  `{{#unless environment.production}}` (when i scaffold with angular cli)

but `npm build` doesn't know to interpret it?

is `ng` calling `npm` or visa versa

Comment: npm build is an internal npm command. if you really have a scripts entry 'build' in your package.json you need to call npm run build. But i guess you have not. ng build is a command provided by angular cli and will start the angular cli build process.